# Script always returning true when parameter is empty

Tags: javascript

I have written the the javascript code that using the request parameter values.

The request is :

```
{
    "mbox": "abc",
    "mboxTrace":true,
    "mboxParameters": {
        "env":"nonprod",
        "pnr":"",
        "ATR":"",
        "travelDate":"",
        "deptTime":"",
        "arrivalTime":"",
        "fltNo":"",
         "SSR":"",
         "ancPurchased":"",
         "userType":"",
         "geo":"",
         "OS":"",
         "deptCity":"",
         "arrivalCity":"",
         "elig":"",
         "AirportTimezone":""
    }
}
```

JavaScript Code is :

```
if (mbox.name == 'abc')
{
    var ancillaryPurchased= "false";
    var ancArray = mbox.param('ancPurchased').split(',');
    //var count = ancArray.length;

    if(ancArray.length >= 1)
    {
        ancillaryPurchased = "true";
    } 
    else
    {
        ancillaryPurchased= "false";
    }   
    return ancillaryPurchased;
}
```

This code is returning true even if the parameter ancPurchased is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you split a empty string here, it returns an array of one elemenent, i.e an empty string :

```
[""]
```

And its length is equal to 1.

Example:

```js
var str = "";

var len = str.split(",").length;

console.log(len);
```

You can modify your code to :

```
var ancArray = mbox.param('ancPurchased').trim() !=="" ?mbox.param('ancPurchased').split(',') : [];
```

Comment: @AmbikaTewari happy to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

An empty string will be split into an array with one empty string.

```
var ancPurchased = '';
var ancArray = ancPurchased.split(',');
ancArray.length
>>> 1
```

You'll want to special-case that:

```
var ancPurchased = '';
var ancArray = (ancPurchased ? ancPurchased.split(',') : []);
ancArray.length
>>> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Performing split on empty string will return an array with one element.
Therefore returning true everytime.